# Parsing data from an Excel cell that has more than one data point in it in R

Tags: r, excel

I have an Excel sheet of patient information. The heading for one of the columns is "Discharge diagnosis" The problem is that some patients were discharged with more than one diagnosis and so more than one diagnosis is in some of the cells, separated by a "/".

I am using R to analyze the data. I am trying to find the frequency of any given discharge diagnosis.

How can I get R to look for a diagnosis no matter how it is presented in a cell?

For example, I want to know the frequency of the discharge diagnosis "flu". Some patients have a diagnosis of "flu" while others have a diagnosis of "flu/pneumonia". How can I get R to recognize both of these as containing "flu"?

Comment: Do you need this by patient? What have you tried? Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Try something like `+grepl("flu", Discharge.diagnosis)` to make a vector of 1s and 0s by patient that you can then tally to get your frequencies (and note that you need to fix the name of that column for R first, using `make.names` if you like).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide a sample dataset, so I've made one up. I assume you're OK with getting the data from Excel since you didn't specifically ask about that.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
pts <- tribble(~Pt, ~Diag, 
               "Bob", "Flu/Pneumonia", 
               "Cathy", "Flu/Explosive Diarrhea", 
               "Carol", "Pneumonia/Syphilis")
```

What I can do next is split the `Diag` column by the `/` character, and then use `unnest` to make a data frame in which each patient gets a record for each diagnosis.

```
pts <- pts %>% 
  mutate(Diags = str_split(Diag, "/")) %>% 
  unnest() 

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Pt    Diag                   Diags             
  <chr> <chr>                  <chr>             
1 Bob   Flu/Pneumonia          Flu               
2 Bob   Flu/Pneumonia          Pneumonia         
3 Cathy Flu/Explosive Diarrhea Flu               
4 Cathy Flu/Explosive Diarrhea Explosive Diarrhea
5 Carol Pneumonia/Syphilis     Pneumonia         
6 Carol Pneumonia/Syphilis     Syphilis
```

Here is a frequency table of diagnoses:

```
pts %>% count(Diags)

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Diags                  n
  <chr>              <int>
1 Explosive Diarrhea     1
2 Flu                    2
3 Pneumonia              2
4 Syphilis               1
```